# Changing an EJB from 2.1 to 3.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, weblogic, ejb-3.0

I have an existing Web Application (Servlet) that remotely accesses an EJB currently written to the EJB 2.1 Specification (`EJBHome`, `EJBObject`, `SessionBean`, all configuration in `ejb-jar.xml`).  The servlet access the EJB via JNDI lookup, the JNDI name being specified in `weblogic-ejb-jar.xml`.

I would like to update the EJB to EJB3.0, which will (hopefully) make it easier to add to the API.

My issue is that I need to do it with a minimum of change to the existing servlet code.  In other words, I still need to:

1. Access the EJB with a *simple*, global JNDI name (it is stored in a database, and the servlet can can change the name it looks up on the fly), and
2. Be able to use the 2.1 style:

   ```
   String jndiName = getJndiName();    // e.g. "BeanV2.0"
   BeanHome home = (BeanHome) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(
           jndiContext.lookup(jndiName), BeanHome.class);
   BeanRemote remote = home.create();
   remote.doBusiness();               // call business method
   ```

I have tried a stripped down version, applying `@RemoteHome`, but I keep getting errors during deployment.

I am deploying (for development/production) on Weblogic, mostly 10.3.5 (11gR1), and am limited to EJB 3.0.  I am using Eclipse (with the Oracle Weblogic Pack) for development.

Thanks.

Comment: go through this link, changes are minimal but depends on your code design. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071804/java-web-development/migrating-ejb-2-x-applications-to-ejb-3-0.html

Comment: @Avinash K.P: I already saw that link.  The article says that DeMichiel presented an example in a 2005 Java One 2005 presentation on EJB 3.0.  Unfortunately, I all links to that presentation point to developers.sun.com - which forwards to the Oracle Java home page :-(.  Searching the Oracle site for the article gave me blogs entries, all of which pointed to old Sun sites.  Any clue where to find that article these days?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to first understand the architectural difference between EJB2.1 and EJB3.x (refer [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsawshlp/v7r5m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.jee5.doc%2Ftopics%2Fcejb3vejb21.html))

You will have some major/minor changes in code based on your bean implementation and client side invocation, because of the removal of `Home` and `Deployment Descriptor` in EJB3.x

Refer this example for accessing EJB3.x from a client, in your case Servlet

```
/**
 * Servlet implementation class SampleServlet
 */
public class SampleServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public SampleServlet() {
    super();
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
            Context ctx=getInitialContext();
            String jndiName=getJndiName();  // eg. java:global/BeanProject/Bean!demo.BeanRemote
            BeanRemote beanRemote = (BeanRemote)ctx.lookup(jndiName);
            remote.doBusiness();

    } catch(Exception exception) {
        System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
    }
}

private static Context getInitialContext() throws Exception
{
    Properties properties=new Properties();
    properties.put("java.naming.factory.initial","org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
    properties.put("java.naming.provider.url","remote://localhost:4447");

    return new InitialContext(properties);
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
}

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, @Adheep.  I read through (nearly) the entire EJB 3.0 (and 3.1) specifications, and implemented a 2.1 and 3.0 bean side by side, so I do understand the difference.  I know about the _new_ (3.0) way to access an EJB; I'm trying to rewrite the EJB in such a way as to not require _any_ changes to the client, at least not right away.  (I may want to update the client in the future, slowly, but I can't do it all in the time frame available.)

Comment: @Menachem, yeah I can understand your problem but I'm sure you would have figured out by now that you cannot migrate to EJB3.x without changing in the client side. But I have a suggestion,
You could have a common proxy ejb implemented in 2.1 whose only work is to invoke a 3.x ejb and return the response to the client

Comment: Actually, @Adheep, the 3.0 Spec (Simplified) does refer to a way to do just that, suggesting the use of `@RemoteHome` to annotate a Home interface.  I could not find any good examples, though, that worked.  jboss has an EJB 3 tutorial that includes an example, but I could not get it to deploy on Weblogic.